# Isogeny of an elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $p$ be a prime. Then what does it mean by "$E$ has a $\mathbb{Q}$-isogeny of degree $p$"?

Comment: If you're in the context of arithmetic geometry, it most likely means an isogeny defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ whose kernel has $p$ elements. In some cases a $\mathbb{Q}$-isogeny is meant as an isogeny tensored with a rational number, but I think the first interpretation is more likely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Robert Auffarth said in a comment, a $\mathbb{Q}$-isogeny of degree $p$ is a non-constant morphism of elliptic curves $E\to E'$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, that sends zero to zero, i.e., $\mathcal{O}_E\mapsto \mathcal{O}_{E'}$, and has degree $p$. Since the degree of the map equals the size of the kernel, the degree $p$ condition means that the kernel has size exactly $p$.

As it turns out (this is hard), there are only $\mathbb{Q}$-rational isogenies  of elliptic curves of degree $p$ for finitely many primes, namely $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,37,43,67$, and $163$.

Comment: Of course, in your last statement, you are excluding the isogenies given by multiplication by $[n]$ on an elliptic curve. So you should say "$\mathbf Q$-rational isogenies of non-isomorphic elliptic curves", I think.

Comment: @Ari, the multiplication by n map has degree n^2, which is not a prime. I am only speaking about isogenies of prime degree.

Comment: You are absolutely right!

Comment: For those who are curious like I was, the list above is proved to be exhaustive in Mazur's [Rational Isogenies of Prime Degree](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01390348.pdf).

Comment: That's correct! I should have pointed this out.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo Do $E$ and $E'$ have to be defined over $\mathbb{Q}$? If we have a 163-isogeny, then its kernel has order 163, and the kernel is a subgroup of $E$. If $E$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, that it can't have a point of order 163, according to Mazur's theorem. What am I missing?

Comment: The individual points in the kernel are not necessarily defined over Q, but rather, the group generated by the points is defined over Q. This means that the kernel is cyclic, generated by a point $P$, such that the Galois conjugates of $P$ are multiples of $P$.